# Как сделать такой свитч

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Всем здравствуйте. Мне нужно сделать вот такой переключатель языка.
Возможно есть какие-то фреймворки или способы сделать это проще?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подобные штуки можно делать с помощью `UISegmentedControl`, который нужно кастомизировать под требования или с помощью двух `UIButton` что проще.

Можете использовать библиотечку: [DGRunkeeperSwitch](https://github.com/gontovnik/DGRunkeeperSwitch)
или [BetterSegmentedControl](https://github.com/gmarm/BetterSegmentedControl)

Comment: Спасибо большое